# Handle a MonoMac Exit/Window Close Event

Tags: macos, events, mono, exit, monomac

Similar to this question I posted earlier: [Handle a WPF Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717222/handle-a-wpf-exit-event)

I found [a solution in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768497/application-exit-event), but I'm not familiar with how to port this with Mono.

**EDIT**

I found that I could use the following override to do what I wanted to:

```
NSApplicationTerminateReply ApplicationShouldTerminate (NSApplication sender)
```

However, there is a problem now if I close my MainWindow since that is actually where I want to start calling application exit. I already have an override for `ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` that returns true, so the terminate override is being called correctly. But when I'm returning Cancel, the app is running, sans window. Is there a way to intercept the window closing event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. I created a new class called `MainWindowDelegate`:

```
public class MainWindowDelegate : MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowDelegate
{
    public override WindowShouldClose (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, in my `MainWindowController` class:

```
public class MainWindowController
{
    private MainWindowDelegate _delegate;

    // Shared initialization code
    void Initialize()
    {
        _delegate = new MainWindowDelegate();
    }

    public override void WindowDidLoad()
    {
        Window.Delegate = _delegate;
    }
}
```